# Poner linearlayout al final de la pantalla en una actividad de mapa

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

Quiero establecer un `layout` en la pantalla,al final del todo. La actividad es un mapa.

Éste es mi código del `layout`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75sp"
    android:background="@color/azulaudiobus"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="20sp"
        android:src="@mipmap/velocidad" />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/tvCartel1"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        android:textSize="40sp" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/altitud" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCartel2"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        android:textSize="40sp" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/longitud" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCartel3"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        android:textSize="40sp" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@mipmap/latitud" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCartel4"
        android:layout_width="200sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
        android:textSize="40sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Tal cual está se alinea todo el tiempo arriba. 
¿Se os ocurre alguna manera de bajar el layout?

Comment: Una actividad de mapa? donde esta el mapa en tu layout?

Answer (score 1):

Englobarlo dentro de otro layout y con android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" lo colocas abajo del padre.

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/azulaudiobus">
<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@color/azulaudiobus"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:orientation="horizontal">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="20sp"
    android:src="@mipmap/velocidad" />

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/tvCartel1"
    android:layout_width="200sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
    android:textSize="40sp" />


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@mipmap/altitud" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCartel2"
    android:layout_width="200sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
    android:textSize="40sp" />


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@mipmap/longitud" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCartel3"
    android:layout_width="200sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
    android:textSize="40sp" />


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@mipmap/latitud" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCartel4"
    android:layout_width="200sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Con esta solucion se come este segundo layout toda la pantalla, los iconos los alinea abajo pero ya no se ve el mapa :S

Comment: Cambia android:layout_height="75sp" a android:layout_height="wrap-content"

Comment: Nada, me he fijado que es el relativelayout lo que se lo come, si le qito el fondo se queda todo blanco y el layout que quiero abajo...pero el mapa sigue sin verse...

Comment: Postea si puedes tu xml exactamente, el Relative es PADRE del LinearLayout que el Relative englobe al Linear